# How to use Javascript replace to change var that was a number

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm missing something very basic here, I think!

```
$(function() {
    $('#zahlungsart_0').click(function() {
            var gesamtsumme_neu = Number($('#gesamtsumme').attr('rel'))+6;
            gesamtsumme_neu.toString;
            gesamtsumme_neu.replace('.',',');
            console.log(gesamtsumme_neu);
            $('#gesamtsumme').text(gesamtsumme_neu);
    });
```

Error: TypeError: gesamtsumme_neu.replace is not a function

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toString` is not a property, it's a function - `toString()`, thus should be called as such. You're also not changing the value of the variable you call it on - you need to assign the return value to [another] variable:

```
$(function() {
    $('#zahlungsart_0').click(function() {
            var gesamtsumme_neu = Number($('#gesamtsumme').attr('rel'))+6;
            var newVal = gesamtsumme_neu.toString().replace('.',',')
            console.log(newVal );
            $('#gesamtsumme').text(newVal);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#zahlungsart_0').click(function() {
            var gesamtsumme_neu = Number($('#gesamtsumme').attr('rel'))+6;
            gesamtsumme_neu = gesamtsumme_neu.toString();
            gesamtsumme_neu = gesamtsumme_neu.replace('.',',');
            console.log(gesamtsumme_neu);
            $('#gesamtsumme').text(gesamtsumme_neu);
    });
```

Assign the values of toString(), replace()
Also toString is a function

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `toString` and reassign it to the variable; just like you have to do with replace. Like this:

```
$(function() {
$('#zahlungsart_0').click(function() {
        var gesamtsumme_neu = Number($('#gesamtsumme').attr('rel'))+6;
        gesamtsumme_neu = gesamtsumme_neu.toString();
        gesamtsumme_neu = gesamtsumme_neu.replace('.',',');
        console.log(gesamtsumme_neu);
        $('#gesamtsumme').text(gesamtsumme_neu);
});
```

The two function don't change the variable you are calling them on but return a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

toString() returns a string, so try this:

```
var q = gesamtsumme_neu.toString();
q = q.replace('.',',');
console.log(q);
// etc
```